# How to set default options for Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I've setup an ASP.NET Core 6 web API using the Microsoft Graph SDK client. In all my requests, I find myself using the lines:

```
.WithAppOnly()
.WithMaxRetry(10)
.WithMaxRetry(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0))
```

Like this:

```
await graphServiceClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs
   .Request()
   .WithAppOnly()
   .WithMaxRetry(10)
   .WithMaxRetry(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0))
   .GetAsync()
```

Is there anyway that I can set this up in Program.cs when I create my client so that I don't need to write the same lines on every call?

Program.cs

```
//add Graph service
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
               .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

AppSettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<< domain >>",
    "TenantId": " <<tenant id >>",
    "ClientId": " << client id >>",
    "ClientSecret": " << client secret >>"
  },

  "Graph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!